# How to ensure caching in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

For improving the performance of the wordpress site, we use WP-Rocket purchased plugin for improving the caching. However, i see the below headers when the page is loaded. I am not sure of whether the caching is enabled.

```
pragma: no-cache

cache-control: no-cache
```

I read that no cache doesn't mean no caching is done. How to ensure that caching in my website is enabled and thereby performance is improved.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma):

> Pragma: no-cache:
>   Same as Cache-Control: no-cache. Forces caches to submit the request
>   to the origin server for validation before releasing a cached copy.

The "no-cache" value might be misleading here but they actually prevent the client from caching the response, ie. disables **browser-caching** not overall server-side caching.

To check up on what type of cache is done/served use an external service, such as [seositecheckup](https://seositecheckup.com/tools/page-cache-test-server-side-caching)